# I want specific word to be stored in a CSV file

Tags: regex, perl

I need a specific word in a file name should be pulled out from file names among directory

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $directory = "/home/grds/datafiles";
opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
@files = grep("EXP", readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

foreach $file (@files) {
  # print "$file\n";
        open ($file
}
```

example file name :

```
EXPresult_3D0R0000002345_test345_cache1_IND0000ASD123_2014_04_12_18_56_1
```

I need

```
3D0R0000002345, test345, cache1, IND0000ASD123, 2014_04_12
```

should be stored in Excel file with separate columns.

Comment: What delimits that text within the filename?

Comment: Does the output file need to be in an Excel-specific format (xls / xlsx), or can it be in a structured text format (csv)?

Comment: it can be in csv format tooo

Comment: Why is there only one digit for the seconds (the trailing `_1`)?  Can there be underscores in the prefix (`EXPresult` in the example)?  What have you tried?  Splitting on `_` and selecting the right bits looks like a promising (simple) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if all you want is a CSV output

This program checks that each directory item is a file (not a directory) and that the name contains `EXP`, and then splits it on underscores `_` to a maximum of six fields. That leaves the trailing date-time intact as a single field

Then the first field is removed, the time is stripped from the last field, and all remaining fields are printed, joined by commas `,`

I have used `autodie` which removes the need to check the success of the `opendir`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use File::Spec::Functions 'rel2abs';

use constant DIRECTORY => '/home/grds/datafiles';

opendir my $dh, DIRECTORY;

while ( my $node = readdir $dh ) {

  my $fullpath = rel2abs($node, DIRECTORY);
  next unless -f $fullpath and $node =~ /EXP/;

  my @fields = split /_/, $node, 6;
  next unless @fields == 6;

  shift @fields;
  $fields[-1] =~ s/\d+_\d+_\d+\K.*//;

  print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
3D0R0000002345,test345,cache1,IND0000ASD123,2014_04_12
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just wrote using Excel::Writer::XLSX you need to install this module to run this script if already not available. You can also take a look at this module on cpan if you need more capability.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $k          = 0;
my $reportfile = "report.xlsx";
my $workbook   = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $reportfile );
die "Problems creating new Excel file: $!" unless defined $workbook;
my $worksheet  = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Excel Format
my $format = $workbook->add_format();

my @val;
opendir( my $dir, "./test/" );
my @file = grep( /EXP/, readdir( $dir ) );
while ( <@file> ) {
    @val = split( /_/, $_ );
    print "$val[1] $val[2] $val[3] $val[4] $val[5]_$val[6]_$val[7]\n";
    $format->set_align( 'top' );
    $worksheet->write( $k, 0, "$val[1]",                 $format );
    $worksheet->write( $k, 1, "$val[2]",                 $format );
    $worksheet->write( $k, 2, "$val[3]",                 $format );
    $worksheet->write( $k, 3, "$val[4]",                 $format );
    $worksheet->write( $k, 4, "$val[5]_$val[6]_$val[7]", $format );
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: Can I have CSV file rather than excel file. I am sorry i did not have excel write:XLSX is not installed in lab pc

Comment: you can install  module using cpan -i  Excel::Writer::XLSX on your lab PC or contact your system admin. I've not tried CSV, probably try looking at "Text::CSV" module in cpan.